# To reset the selected input field in angular

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6

I have component to `edit` and add back some multiple `address` dynamically, The UI looks like this:

[image]

After adding/editing a particular `address` . I am resetting the whole **form** field values. In order to a new `address` like this:

[image]

But i want to empty only the `address` input fields (means Type,city...) On clicking **add** button.
[image]

but now on clicking `add` button i am resetting all form field values(ex **name** is also resetting as shown in the second image).
How can i reset only **address fields input** values? On clicking **add** button.

[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-movie-read-load-json-sample-eg-a5wfbv?file=src/app/edit/edit.component.ts)

Comment: Please fix the errors in your stackBlitz.

Comment: Directly don't click on the `edit` button select one contact from the `list` then click edit, You won't see any error then.

Comment: find updated stackblitz https://angular-movie-read-load-json-sample-eg-f8xcyq.stackblitz.io

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can reset a particular field in angular as follows:

```
this.yourForm.controls['field_name'].reset()
```

Instead of resetting entire form using `form.reset()`; try resetting the specific fields you want.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of resetting whole form try to reset only field that you want to clear.

Get individual field reference formControl object like below

```
get addressType() {
    return this.editForm.get('addressType');   }

get city() {
    return this.editForm.get('city');   }

get postalCode() {
    return this.editForm.get('postalCode');   }
```

then `onSubmit` form set value to empty using `setValue('')`

```
this.addressType.setValue('');
this.city.setValue('');
this.postalCode.setValue('');
```

**Please find solution on [fork stackblitz](https://angular-movie-read-load-json-sample-eg-f8xcyq.stackblitz.io)**

Answer (score 0):

Another way you can reset data like below,

`this.newAttribute.addressType = this.newAttribute.postalCode = this.newAttribute.city = "";`